# MD5 vs CRC32: Which one's better for common use?

Tags: algorithm, hash

Recently I read somewhere that although both CRC32 and MD5 are sufficiently uniform and stable, CRC32 is more efficient than MD5. MD5 seems to be a very commonly used hashing algorithm but if CRC32 is faster/more memory efficient then why not use that?

Comment: They serve different purposes completely. For one, CRCs don't avalanche, making them terrible hash functions: http://home.comcast.net/~bretm/hash/8.html

Comment: Basically, what CRC is supposed to do is tell you when some amount of bits becomes corrupted. The desired property is: "for small changes to a message, obtain a result that is different". For hashes, the desired behaviour is much stronger: "for any two messages, the result should be **wildly** different". If you want a fast high-quality hash that's not necessarily cryptographically secure, I'd consider Bob Jenkins' SpookyHash: http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/spooky.html (Warning: C++.)

Comment: For reference: "avalanching" basically means that for any message, if **one** single bit of the input flips, the probability of **every** single output bit flipping should be as close to 50% as possible. This is absolutely essential for cryptographical purposes. For use in hash tables, I also believe that this would prevent collisions/clustering - and conversely lack of avalanching would contribute to them - but I can't really back this up with math.

Comment: Also: http://blog.reverberate.org/2012/01/state-of-hash-functions-2012.html

Comment: Depends what you want the value for: see other comments and answers below.
* error detection * hashing (ie distributing values over a number space) * message digest

Answer (score 73, accepted):

**MD5** is a ***one-way-hash*** algorithm. One-way-hash algorithms are often used in cryptography as they have the property (per design) that it's hard to find the input that produced a specific hash value. Specifically it's hard to make two different inputs that give the same one-way-hash. They are often used as a way to show that an amount of data has not been altered intentionally since the hash code was produced. As the MD5 is a ***one-way-hash*** algorithm the emphasis is on security over speed. Unfortunately MD5 is now considered insecure.

**CRC32** is designed to detect accidental changes to data and is commonly used in networks and storage devices. The purpose of this algorithm is not to protect against intentional changes, but rather to catch accidents like network errors and disk write errors, etc. The emphasis of this algorithm is more on speed than on security.

Comment: Well, CRC32 does not address "security" in the cryptographic sense, at all. The emphasis is on error-detection capability, with resistance to factors such as leading/trailing zeros/ones, burst errors, repeated bits, changes in message length, etc. - in conjunction with comparative simplicity to implement in terms of hardware logic (which will usually operate at the data bit-rate), and hence, speed of operation in a software implementation.

Answer (score 22):

From [Wikipedia's article on MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) (emphasis mine):

> MD5 is a widely used **cryptographic hash function**

Now [CRC32](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRC32):

> CRC is an **error-detecting code**

So, as you can see, CRC32 *is not a hashing algorithm*. That means you should not use it for hashing, because it was not built for that.

And I think it doesn't make much sense to talk about common use, because similar algorithms are used for different purposes, each with significantly different requirements. There is no single algorithm that's best for common use, instead, you should choose the algorithm that's most suited for your specific use.

Comment: CRC32 is a [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_hash_functions) but it is not a _cyrptographic_ hash function.

Comment: @mehaase It does technically satisfy the definition of a hash function. But it was not build to be one, and so it's not a good idea to use it as a hash function, cryptographic or otherwise.

Comment: CRC has a good uniform distribution to be a hash-function. So you could use it for that purpose. But you usually don't need that quality of hashing for a hashtable.

Comment: but CRC is used for hashing in Redis partitioning

Comment: @svick "it's not a good idea to use it as a hash function, cryptographic or otherwise" for sharding (assigning data to buckets) upside of CRC over MD5 is efficiency. What are the downsides?

Comment: @AleksandrLevchuk No guarantee of good distribution of items into buckets. You might want to look into modern non-cryptographic hash functions, instead of CRC or MD5.

Answer (score 13):

It depends on your goals. Here are some examples what can be done with CRC32 versus MD5:

**Detecting duplicate files**

If you want to check if two files are the same, CRC32 checksum is the way to go because it's faster than MD5. But be careful: CRC only reliably tells you if the binaries are different; it doesn't tell you if they're identical. If you get different hashes for two files, they cannot be the same file, so you can reject them as being duplicates very quickly.

No matter what your keys are, the CRC32 checksum will be one of 2^32 different values. Assuming random sample files, the probability of collision between the hashes of two given files is 1 / 2^32. The probability of collisions between any of N given files is (N - 1) / 2^32.

**Detecting malicious software**

If security is an issue, like downloading a file and checking the source's hash against yours to see if the binaries aren't corrupted, then CRC is a poor option. This is because attackers can make malware that will have the same CRC checksum. In this case, an MD5 digest is more secure -- CRC was not made for security. Two different binaries are far more likely to have the same CRC checksum than the same MD5 digest.

**Securing passwords for user authentication**

Synchronous (one-way) encryption is usually easier, faster, and more secure than asynchronous (two-way) encryption, so it's a common method to store passwords. Basically, the password will be combined with other data (salts) then the hash will be done on all of this combined data. Random salts greatly reduce the chances of two passwords being the same. By default, the same password will have the same hash for most algorithms, so you must add your own randomness. Of course, the salt must be saved externally.

To log a user in, you just take the information they give you when they log in. You use their username to get their salt from a database. You then combine this salt with the user's password to get a new hash. If it matches the one in in the database, then their login is successful. Since you're storing these passwords, they must be VERY secure, which means a CRC checksum is out of the question.

Cryptographic digests are more expensive to compute than CRC checksums. Also, better hashes like sha256 are more secure, but slower for hashing and take up more database space (their hashes are longer).

Answer (score 7):

One big difference between CRC32 and MD5 is that it is usually easy to pick a CRC32 checksum and then come up with a message that hashes to that checksum, even if there are constraints imposed on the message, whereas MD5 is specifically designed to make this sort of thing difficult (although it is showing its age - this is now possible in some situations).

If you are in a situation where it is possible that an adversary might decide to sit down and create a load of messages with specified CRC32 hashes, to mimic other messages, or just to make a hash table perform very badly because everything hashes to the same value, then MD5 would be a better option. (Even better, IMHO, would be HMAC-MD5 with a keyed value that is unique to the module using it and unknown outside it).

Comment: I would take issue with your use of the phrase "a message that hashes to that checksum" - I know what you mean, but would suggest something like "shares the same CRC value" - since it's *not* a "hash" function.

Comment: CRC32 is not a _cryptographic_ hash, but it can be used as a hash function. The original post specifically mentioned hash functions. CRC fits within the definition of a hash function as at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function, and is specifically mentioned there (although with some very dubious suggestions about using only the top 16 bits).

Answer (score 5):

CRCs are used to guard against random errors, for example in data transmission.

Cryptographic hash functions are designed to guard against intelligent adversaries forging the message, though MD5 has been broken in that respect.

Answer (score 4):

You should use MD5 which is 128bit long.
CRC32 is only 32 bit long and its purpose is to detect errors not to hash things.
In case you need only a 32bit hash function you can choose 32 bits that are returned by MD5 the LSBs/MSBs/Whatever.

Answer (score 4):

The primary reason CRC32 (or CRC8, or CRC16) is used for any purpose whatsoever is that it can be cheaply implemented *in hardware* as a means of detecting "random" corruption of data.  Even in software implementations, it can be useful as a means of detecting random corruption of data from hardware causes (such as noisy communications line or unreliable flash media).  It is not tamper-resistant, nor is it generally suitable for testing whether two arbitrary files are likely to be the same: if each chunk of data in file is immediately followed by a CRC32 of that chunk (some data formats do that), each chunk will have the same effect on the overall file's CRC as would a chunk of all zero bytes, regardless of what data was stored in that chunk.

If one has the means to calculate a CRC32 quickly, it might be helpful in conjunction with other checksum or hash methods, if different files that had identical CRC's would be likely to differ in one of the other hashes and vice versa, but on many machines other checksum or hash methods are likely to be easier to compute relative to the amount of protection they provide.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, CRC32 is **not faster** than MD5 is.

Please take a look at: https://3v4l.org/2MAUr

That php script runs several hashing algorithms and measures the time spent to calculate the hashes by each algorithm. It shows that MD5 is generally the fastest hashing algorithm around. And, it shows that even SHA1 is faster than MD5 in most of the test cases.

So, anyway, if you want to do some quick error-detection, or look for random changes... I would always advice to go with MD5, as it simply does it all.

Comment: You are measuring here the relative speed of PHP implementations, not the speed of algorithms. Seems like PHP poorly implemented crc32. CRC32 IS much faster than MD5, when a cryptographic library is properly implement. Thanks to crc32c hadware accelleration available on latest Intel CPUs, you can compute a crc32c at the speed of the memory bandwidth (more than 4GB/s on my PC), whereas MD5 does not pipeline and even the most optimized versions are much slower.

Comment: Update from 2021, seems that PHP8.0 has improved the speed, where crc32 was ~2x slower than md5 in PHP<=7.4, in 8.0 it is ~10x faster

Answer (score 2):

I would say if you **don't know what to choose**, go for `md5`.

It's less probable to cause you a headache.

It covers all cases where `crc32` would be more preferable. The only thing that you would sacrifice for these cases is efficiency (* and maybe what is described on [cup's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16122653/1555615) regarding bits, when data chunks are very small).
On the contrary if you choose `crc32` in cases where `md5sum` is needed you would sacrifice more critical things like security and for some contexts even data integrity.

**Conclusion: use CRC32 only if you know what you are doing.**

Answer (score 1):

One man's common is another man's infrequent.  Common varies depending on which field you are working in.

If you are doing very quick transmissions or working out hash codes for small items, then CRCs are better since they are a lot faster and the chances of getting the same 16 or 32 bit CRC for wrong data are slim.

If it is megabytes of data, for instance, a linux iso, then you could lose a few megabytes and still end up with the same CRC.  Not so likely with MD5.  For that reason MD5 is normally used for huge transfers.  It is slower but more reliable.

So basically, if you are going to do one huge transmission and check at the end whether you have the correct result, use MD5.  If you are going to transmit in small chunks, then use CRC.

Comment: “If you are […] working out hash codes for small items, then CRCs are better” No, they are not. *CRC is not a hashing algorithm.*

Comment: Any algorithm that maps a large dataset to a smaller dataset can be used as a hashing algorithm.  It may not be a particularly good one in that you may get a lot of collisions but it can still be used.

Comment: But you're not saying that you *can* use CRC as a hashing algorithm, you're saying that you *should* use it (under some circumstances).

Comment: "if you are going to do one huge transmission and check at the end whether you have the correct result" - the thing is, this isn't hashing. While it's true that hash functions *can* be used to detect transmission errors (since they have very - even needlessly - strong guarantees on diffusion), it's wrong to conflate the concepts. I also strongly doubt there's a non-negligible probability of CRC giving you the same results after you lop off a random chunk off an ISO.

Comment: A CRC will detect all: 
* 1 or 2 bit errors
* odd number of errors 
* error burst same width as the CRC value