# Unix : cksum comparison between files in a folder

Tags: shell, unix, checksum

There are thousands of files in my src folder.I have src and src_temp folders name, both are same in terms of files but files cksum may differ.

I want to compare files in the folder against cksum so that i can see which files are different.

Please let me know the way.

I checked this [link](http://www.unix.com/showthread.php?t=126343) as well but dont know which one is good to check thousands of files.

Found :

```
$ # go to directory dir1
$ cd dir1
$
$ ls | sort | xargs cksum
1958180199 14 file1
1994293486 14 file2
1996893289 14 file3
$
$ # now do the same for directory dir2
$ cd ../dir2
$
$ ls | sort | xargs cksum
1958180199 14 file1
1994293486 14 file2
1996893289 14 file3
```

then diff of files.. .there are thousands of file. Can we have any other good approach

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @ Lutz Horn : updated what i found on net..but didn't find it good.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bash loop to compare files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413097/bash-loop-to-compare-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Files:

```
$ cat f1/foo.txt   
foo
$ cat f1/bar.txt
bar
$ cat f2/foo.txt 
fooX
$ cat f2/bar.txt
bar
```

Script:

```
for f in f1/*
do
  b=$(basename $f)
  m1=$(md5sum f1/$b | cut -d' ' -f1)
  m2=$(md5sum f2/$b | cut -d' ' -f1)
  if [ "$m1" != "$m2" ]
  then
    echo $b is different
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
foo.txt is different
```

Comment: Then use `chksum` instead of `md5sum`. `cut` is only used to extract the interesting part from the output.

Comment: The correct way to use the cut command would be `cut -f 1 -d' '` (space between f and 1). Also, the command should be `cksum`. For speed reasons, I'd recommend cksum, particularly if there is no reason to believe that that data has been altered intentionally. cksum is better suited in this circumstance. The difference between md5 and crc is well described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122067/ddg#16125537

Answer (score 3):

Rsync can do this comparison for you

`rsync -n -avrc folder1 folder2`

If you have your other folder on some other machine

`rsync -n -avrc folder1/* server2:/home/myuser/folder2`

-n option just does comparison without doing actual rsync